# Accessing variables from other classes

Tags: java, class, user-interface, variables

I have two classes. One class works does the calculations, whilst the other is a GUI to present them.

My problem is - I have "hard coded" a file path into my calculations class and can't seem to find a way to make it dynamic. As the code is fairly long, I uploaded it. Please tell me if you'd prefer me to paste it here.

GUI Class:
http://pastebin.com/qNU7jVV0

Calculations Class:
http://pastebin.com/rSGr9KL7

A solution in simple terms would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to set the jpegFile field in yoru GUI Class?

Comment: Yes. So the jpegFile isn't hardcoded and will be changed when the user hits the "Search Button" (If possible, set the jpegFile to "path" as that is the variable set when the user selects a file").

Comment: Please look at pastebin or some other site with code highlighting and indenting, this really sucks. Oh, and please leave out all the non-relevant stuff, it's just clutter.

Comment: Point taken Leon. Give me a minute and I will edit.

Comment: Reduce your code to a minimal example. Indent it properly. Join it to your question. And please learn about exceptions: your methods may throw exceptions. A method that can't deal with an exception shouldn't catch it. And no, printing "error 2" to the console is not dealing with an exception.

Comment: JB, I know that print "error 2" is not the official way of dealing with exceptions. I just wanted to know which errors were what. Like I said in my original post, I've just started out with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Calculations Class:

```
public File setFile(String filepath){
    try{
        jpegFile = new File(filepath);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.PrintStackTrace();
    }
    return jpegFile;
}
```

now in GUI, to set the file to the given file path, just call `metaData.setFile("C:\mypic.jpg");`

Comment: Well, the idea is that if you have a string somewhere that stores the correct file path, whenever you update that string, you then do a `metaData.setFile(storedFilePath);` to update the relevant field in your metadata class